# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Landroidx/concurrent/futures/CallbackToFutureAdapter$Resolver in Espresso UI Test

Tags: android, android-espresso

I'm encountering the following exception while running an Android Espresso UI test in Android Studio:

Java:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/concurrent/futures/CallbackToFutureAdapter$Resolver;
> at androidx.test.core.app.DeviceCapture$forceRedrawGlobalWindowViews$1.run(DeviceCapture.kt:168)

Has anyone faced this issue before? How can I resolve it?

Verified the Espresso library version is up to date
added this in proguard

```
"-keep class androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter$Completer { *;}"
```